# Ways to give SQL Query to PSQL Command line

Tags: java, bash, postgresql, psql

I'm looking for different ways other than -c or --command= to give SQL queries to PSQL command line.

What are alternatives to this:

```
String command2 = "psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123 -c 'ALTER TABLE audit ALTER COLUMN event TYPE character varying(3000);'";
```

Following select query works:

```
String command2 = "psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123 -c 'SELECT * FROM audit'";
```

Then why does the Alter query does not work?

Some background if needed:

I'm using io.kubernetes library in Java. I want to execute a psql command on a container with postgres.

Following does not work:

```
String command2 = "psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123 -c 'ALTER TABLE audit ALTER COLUMN event TYPE character varying(3000);'";

String command[]  = new String[] { "bash", "-c", command2 };
Exec exec = new Exec();
Process exec2 = exec.exec(namespace, podName, command, dbContainerName, stdIn, stdOut);
Thread.sleep(10000);
exec2.destroy();
```

In the inputstream, I'm getting following error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

When I use the same sql query with kubernetes command line, it works:

```
kubectl exec -it pod -c container -- bash -c "psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123 -c 'ALTER TABLE audit ALTER COLUMN event TYPE character varying(3000);'"
```

Then why is the Exec through java library not working?

Are there any other ways to give the Alter SQL queries to the PSQL command?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use JDBC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with `;`

For anyone looking at this question, please not this kubernetes api considers ; as EOF and hence it is not able to find the matching quote.

I removed ; and its working.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other ways to give the Alter SQL queries to the PSQL command?

You can pass the query through STDIN.

> Then why does the Alter query does not work?

Can't say for sure, but to me it looks like you're missing quotes for the `-c` argument that you're passing to `bash`:

```
String command2 = "psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123 -c 'ALTER TABLE audit ALTER COLUMN event TYPE character varying(3000);'";
String command[]  = new String[] { "bash", "-c", command2 };
```

The command you're building will be:

```
bash -c psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123 -c 'ALTER TABLE audit ALTER COLUMN event TYPE character varying(3000);'
```

When it should be:

```
bash -c "psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123 -c 'ALTER TABLE audit ALTER COLUMN event TYPE character varying(3000);'"
```

But why pass it to `bash`? Why not simply execute this?

```
psql --dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123 -c 'ALTER TABLE audit ALTER COLUMN event TYPE character varying(3000);'
```

Or better, execute that and pass the query through STDIN:

```
String query = "ALTER TABLE audit ALTER COLUMN event TYPE character varying(3000)";
String command[] = new String[] { "psql", "--dbname=postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:1234/db123" };
Exec exec = new Exec();
Process exec2 = exec.exec(namespace, podName, command, dbContainerName, query, stdOut);
Thread.sleep(10000);
exec2.destroy();
```

Comment: The stdIN parameter is boolean, hence cannot pass query like that

Comment: My bad. Still, I guess you could drop `bash` here.